# How Doghan Daguis's info can lose its value?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

Laureline said these words to Doghan Daguis after she heard an alert in section B. Actually Doghan Daguis gave some info about Mül Converter to Laureline just before this alert:

> It appears **your info just lost its value**. Now get out of my face.
>   Move, pigeons.

Comment: Information, such as warning of an impending attack, is valuable up until the attack has started. Another example is the weather report for yesterday.

Comment: Are you asking in general terms how information can lose value or what caused this specific information to lose its value? The former would not be on-topic for this site, and your question would be closed.

Comment: I edited the post now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their information on offer is the *identity* of the armed mercenaries looking for Valerian and Laureline (or rather the thing on her belt).

However, once the Pearl soldiers have actually appeared on Valerian's scanners just a few corridors away, the information is no longer useful **since they're going to find out very shortly who's chasing them, whether they want to or not.**